# keep getting 'only length-1 arrays can be converted to python scalars'

Tags: python, numpy, square-root, elementwise-operations

I keep getting the error `only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. I am getting error due to the variable 'uc' as it is an array of 214 elements.

The error states:

```
  File "/home/lokesh/PycharmProjects/Cross_Range_Imaging/Cross_Range.py", line 68, in <module>
    dis = cmath.sqrt(Xc ** 2 + (Yc + yn[i] - uc) ** 2)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Tried code:

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np

cj = cmath.sqrt(-1)
pi2 = 2 * cmath.pi
c = 3e8
fc = 200e6
Xc = 1e3
Yc = 0
Y0 = 100
L = 400
theta_c = cmath.atan(Yc / Xc)
L_min = max(Y0, L)
lamda = c / fc
Xcc = Xc / np.power(np.cos(theta_c),2)
duc = (Xcc * lamda) / (4 * Y0)
mc = 2 * math.ceil(L_min / duc)
uc = duc * np.arange(-mc / 2, mc/2)
k = pi2 / lamda

yn = [0, 70, 66.2500, -80]
fn = [1, 1, 1, 1]
ntarget = 4
s = np.zeros((1, mc))

for i in np.arange(ntarget):
    dis = cmath.sqrt(Xc ** 2 + (Yc + yn[i] - uc) ** 2)
    s = s + np.multiply(fn[i] * np.exp(-cj * 2 * k * dis), (abs(uc) <= L))
```

The expected result values of variable 'dis' are `1x214 double` and variable 's' are `1x214 complex double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dis = np.sqrt(Xc ** 2 + (Yc + yn[i] - uc) ** 2)`.

[cmath.sqrt](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) operates on scalars, not arrays.  You have to use an array operation like `numpy.sqrt()` to get the square root of each value in the array.

Note: this will create `dis` with shape `(214,)`, which will still work for setting `s`, but if you want `dis` to be `(1,214)` you may want to add `.reshape(1, 214)` to the end of my suggested code.